# Trash can shortcut missing in Thunar

Tags: 12.10, xubuntu, xfce, thunar

On Xubuntu 12.10 64-bit, the trash can icon shortcut is missing on the side pane in the Thunar file manager. Is there anyway to restore it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is a bug on Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunar/+bug/1057610

Answer (score 2):

Your screenshot looks like it is a rather pristine install of thunar. 
Normally, the behaviour you want will be pulled in if you install the `xubuntu-desktop` package.

You might get the trash back without the xubuntu stuff if you install the recommendations of `thunar` via terminal:

```
# apt-cache depends thunar
```

or via synaptic package manager.

Comment: Thanks so much! The apt-cache command recommended dbus, which made me realize I had to check AT-SPI D-Bus bus in the Session and Startup settings. BTW, the pristineness comes from clearlooks-phenix-master.

Comment: Nevermind, the problem is happening again...

Comment: Then I guess its the missing package `gvfs-daemons`. If there is a daemon named `/usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-trash` running, thunar can attach to and use it.

Comment: I have the same problem. I have everything installed, but no `/usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-trash` process is in `ps ax`. How can I restore it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gvfs gvfs-backends gvfs-fuse
```

It worked for me on antiX distro.